# How do you test regular JavaScript code that does not export anything?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

Normally you import functions, objects and classes from your file and then fiddle around with them in your tests.

But how do you test code that does not export anything but rather is just a bunch of function calls and assignments?

Comment: The code is doing something, right? Check that the output of the code is whatever you expect it to be.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, how do I run the whole file from the test though? You can run an imported function, but a whole file? Do I use eval() or something like that?

Comment: How do you run it now? In your test you can just import the entire file - it will execute immediately, but that should be ok if you do the import inside of the test

Comment: Ex: `const testResult = require('myFile')(...anyParamsToPass)`. Another option is to just export the functions from the file - exporting things won't hurt any of your code in production

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, yes! Importing the whole file! That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, Post this as an answer, I will mark it as a solution if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the whole file. Think of it as a function that executes immediately when you import it. So, just make sure to only import it when you are ready to execute the test:

```
const testResult = require('myFile')(...anyParamsToPass);
```

Another option if you can modify the code is of course to just export the various functions.